# Chrome driver chrushes during parsing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to get information from each post from this [website](https://www.afd.de/presse/)
for this I use the next code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep 
from tqdm import tqdm 

browser = Chrome('AFD/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.afd.de/presse/'
browser.get(url)

posts = browser.find_elements (By.CLASS_NAME, 'blog-shortcode-post-title')

results = []
for post in posts:
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    actions.move_to_element(post)
    post.click()

    page_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    paragraphs = soup.findAll('p')
    paragraphs = soup.find('div', class_='post-content').findAll('p')

    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        paragraph_texted = paragraph.text
        results.append(paragraph_texted)
    sleep(3)
    browser.back()
    sleep(3)
```

Everything goes OK until this [post](https://www.afd.de/stephan-brandner-harte-strafen-statt-dialog-mit-klimaterroristen/)

When script tries to click the link the chromedriver crushes and this error occurs [image]

So, what's going wrong?

Comment: I think the first line of your error says exactly what is going wrong - the output exceeds the size limit.

Comment: @takendarkk no, that means that the output is too big to fit in output line in VS code. But all information should be in 'results' variable. By the end of the script execution the variable has paragraphs only from the first four posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that it is probably not worthwhile to scrape the website, just extract the links and iterate over them instead of clicking around and going `.back` everytime.

Also use a [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select the specific element:

```
...
browser.get(url)
    
posts = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.blog-shortcode-post-title a')]

results = []
for post in posts:
    browser.get(post)
...
```

Some additional things:

- Be aware that there is also a consent pop up that can collide with the link. You could wait for it and click it first if needed.
- It is not necessary to use `selenium` just go with `requests`
- In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)